# Man text document is in 'italicised Arial' and not 'normal Arial' font

Tags: fonts, fontspec, arial

I am using overleaf for a document with Arial 12 and 1.5 line spacing. After multiple attempts I was able to compile the document but for some reason the main text is appearing italicised-Arial instead of normal-Arial. I have installed all the necessary arial fonts (.ttf) files in my tex directory but am not able to resolve this problem. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

[image: Pic attached for reference]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.25}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{Warwick.bib} %Import the bibliography file

%%%%Arial font begins %%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
% Arial
\setmainfont[Path = ./, BoldFont=arialbd.ttf, ItalicFont=ariali.ttf, BoldItalicFont=arialbi.ttf
]{arial.ttf}

%%%%%%%%%Arial font ends %%%%%%%
\title{Data Driven Discovery of Deservedness In VC Industry- A Startup-O Perspective}
\author{XYZ}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
At one of the live radio shows, as the radio jockey congratulated the founder-CEO of the organisation, he expressed his gratitude.....
Is this the best method ? That remains a matter of discussion and `time'.

\printbibliography %Prints bibliography

\end{document}
```

```
=========log file begins========
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)  (format=lualatex 2020.9.10)  12 NOV 2020 13:02
 system commands enabled.
**trial2.tex
(./trial2.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-05-01 2.71 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-05-01 2.71 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/ge
neric-dev/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2020-05-06.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-
2020-05-06.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 0x1.8e353f7ced917p+1
Lua module: luaotfload-fallback 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / fallback
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Lua module: luaotfload-script 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / Script help
ers
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/ge
neric-dev/names".
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-define 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / databa
se
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-plug 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / database
Inserting `Harf pre_output_filter callback' at position 1 in `pre_output_filter'
.
Inserting `Harf wrapup_run callback' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `Harf finish_pdffile callback' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `Harf glyph_info callback' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-suppress 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / suppress
Lua module: luaotfload-szss 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-tounicode 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / tounicod
e
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2020-07-17> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/lat
ex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cac
he/generic-dev/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count164
\c@section=\count165
\c@subsection=\count166
\c@subsubsection=\count167
\c@paragraph=\count168
\c@subparagraph=\count169
\c@figure=\count170
\c@table=\count171
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty (/usr/loc
al/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/t
exlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-07-17 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-06-29 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count172
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
))
Package: xparse 2020-05-15 L3 Experimental document command parser

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.
tex
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count173
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count174
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count175
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count176
))
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2020/02/21 2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (/
usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count185
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count186
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count187
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen136
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen137
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
luaotfload | aux : font no 28 (nil) defines no feature for script latn
luaotfload | aux : font no 28 (nil) defines no feature for script dflt

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'arial.ttf(0)' created for font 'arial.ttf'
(fontspec)             with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,BoldFont=arialbd.ttf,ItalicFont=ariali.ttf
,BoldItalicFont=arialbi.ttf].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[arial.ttf]:mode=node;language=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[arialbd.ttf]:mode=node;language=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[ariali.ttf]:mode=node;language=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[arialbi.ttf]:mode=node;language=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.: 

(/compile/output.aux)
\openout1 = output.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 1.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/arial.ttf(0)/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/arial.ttf(0)/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/arial.ttf(0)/m/n --> TU/arial.ttf(0)/m/n on input lin
e 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/arial.ttf(0)/m/it on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/arial.ttf(0)/b/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/arial.ttf(0)/m/n --> TU/arial.ttf(0)/b/n on input lin
e 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/arial.ttf(0)/b/it on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 1.
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/compi
le/output.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 3006 strings out of 481315
 100000,460012 words of node,token memory allocated
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:15,3:2,4:1,5:21,6:1,7:16,9:7
 20217 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 32 fonts using 4218827 bytes
 44i,4n,73p,390b,228s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
<./arial.ttf>
Output written on output.pdf (1 page, 9873 bytes).

PDF statistics: 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
============log file ends==============
```

Comment: As always on this this, please post full minimal examples, not sniplets like this weere others have to guess a lot of stuff to even be able to test your code.

Comment: Try a minimal example `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=arialbd.ttf, ItalicFont=ariali.ttf, BoldItalicFont=arialbi.ttf]{arial.ttf}

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}`, compile with lualatex and then show the log-file.

Comment: also never use inputenc package with lualatex

Comment: @daleif apologies for that. Have edited the code which produced similar result as shown in pic. Hope the same repeats at your end for a solution.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, tried out the minimal code and got the same result (italicised Arial).

Comment: fine, so you did 2 of 3 things I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I got the log but wondering where to upload. Sorry for this dumb question :-).

Comment: pastebin, dropbox, github, whatever. Or copy it in the question.

Comment: @jaycee4u we can not run the code in your question (no `\documentclass` and it references a bib file we don't have) please remove all the unrelated code and make a small example that we can test

Comment: is Arial even available on overleaf? It is normally only available on windows machines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Edited the code, you can try now. You are right Arial is not available but there are workarounds. Trying one of them and everything went smooth until the normal text got italicised.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Edited the question and added log content at the bottom.

Comment: you only appear to have uploaded arial not the other variants such as arialbd (although uploading any them is not normally allowed by the font licence)

Comment: where did you get the ttf from? Which version has the font? I tested with the versions from my windows and it works fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I downloaded the fonts from the Web. Therein lies the problem I believe. I didn't quite understand the version part of your question. If you meant the version of the font files then I need to check. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, the problem was with the font file. Thanks so much for pointing it out.

Comment: Off topic:  You have `\usepackage{biblatex}` twice, once with options, once not.  Remove the latter -- not needed.